# Error while parsing JSON response in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

The following code throws error at statement :

```
Result res = (Result)stdserialize.ReadObject(ms);
```

And the error is : There was an error deserializing the object of type TrackLocation.MainPage+Result. End element 'types' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'item' from namespace ''.

```
HttpClient gClientRequest = new HttpClient();
System.Uri gURI = new Uri("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true");
HttpResponseMessage gResponse = await gClientRequest.GetAsync(gURI);
string   strStream = await gResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strStream));
DataContractJsonSerializer stdserialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Result));
Result res = (Result)stdserialize.ReadObject(ms);
```

//################################################################################################

```
[DataContract]
public class Address
{
    [DataMember(Name = "long_name")]
    public string address1;
    [DataMember(Name = "short_name")]
    public string shortaddress;
    [DataMember(Name = "formatted_address")]
    public string formattedtaddress;
    [DataMember(Name = "lat")]
    public string latitude;
    [DataMember(Name = "long")]
    public string latitude;
}
//###############################################################################################



[DataContract]
    public class Result
    {           

        [DataMember(Name = "results")]
        public Address[] Results { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Address
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "formatted_address")]
        public string FormattedAddress;

        [DataMember(Name = "address_components")]
        public AddressComponent[] AddressComponents;
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class AddressComponent
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "long_name")]
        public string LongName;

        [DataMember(Name = "short_name")]
        public string ShortName;

        [DataMember(Name = "types")]
        public string Types;
    }
```

any idea how to fix this issue.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just converted the JSON to XMl and found the types to be repeated(check screen shot below) but in your datacontract its
            [DataMember(Name = "types")]
            public string Types;

Just put this as

```
        [DataMember(Name = "types")]
        public string[] Types;
```

and it should work
[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the JSON, your `Type` field of the `AddressComponent` should be `string[]` not `string`.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "285",
               "short_name" : "285",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
```

Also, you seem to have two `Address` classes and a `result` (lowercase) and `Result` (uppercase) class; I'm assuming those were cut-and-paste issues since they don't seem to match the JSON that's returned.

Comment: removed the additional result class.it was not in my code.And AddressComponent is already an array in Address class.

Comment: I made AddressComponent members such as long_name,short_name and types as string[] instead of string.Now it gives me the error : Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''.

Comment: ONLY the Types field (corresponding to the types attributed in your JSON) of AddressComponent needs to be string[], the others were fine